# How is a Swift CGVector created with dx and dy (derivative)?

Tags: ios, swift, math

I'm trying to understand how a Vector is created in Swift, because when I do CGVectorMake(), tells me to pass a dx and dy (derivative) as a CGFloat.
How can I create a Vector (line) with only that information?

Can anyone explain me ? Like for dummies? I searched in Google but I still couldn't find an easy explanation.

Let's say I would like to create a Vector that goes from point (0,0) to point (5,5).

Comment: Isn't `dx` just `5 - 0` and `dy` just `5 - 0`?

Comment: `dx` and `dy` stand for "delta x", "delta y", not for the derivative.

Comment: Oh.. so it's delta? but how is the point expressed in only 1 CGFloat?

Comment: `CGVectorMake(2.0, 3.0)` or `CGVector(dx: 2.0, dy: 3.0)` takes *two* floats

Comment: I understand, takes 2 floats, but one is X and the other one is Y, how can you represent 2 points to create a vector with that?

Comment: dx is the x-coordinate of the vector and dy is the y-coordinate of the vector. The dx and dy values can be integer, double or float values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many possible representations of vectors, one is as the
"distance" or "displacement" from one point to another point (compare [Euclidean vector: Representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Representations)).

In that sense, the vector from (0,0) to (5,5) is *identical* to the
vector from (2,3) to (7, 8), and the vector from point A to point B
can be computed as

```
let pA = CGPoint(x: 2, y: 3) // Point A(2, 3)
let pB = CGPoint(x: 7, y: 8) // Point B(7, 8)
let vecAB = CGVector(dx: pB.x - pA.x, dy: pB.y - pA.y) // Vector from A to B
print(vecAB) // CGVector(dx: 5.0, dy: 5.0)
```

So `dx`, `dy` stand for "delta X" and "delta Y", the distance of 
the points in x- and y-direction. In the above case, you can
read `vecAB` as "move 5 units in x-direction and 5 units
in y-direction", and you would get the same result for `A(0, 0)`
and `B(5, 5)`.

A "line segment" from (0, 0) to (5, 5) or from (2, 3) to (7, 8)
 cannot be represented by a
vector alone. You would need two points, or one point and one vector.

Comment: Thanks! i get it know!

Comment: So having 2 points I can actually create a Vector to use on applyImpulse, right?

Comment: You can compute a vector from two points, as shown above, so: yes.

Comment: Okay, looks like it works, but the impulse given is so small that the ball does a really small jump. So i think i have to basically increase the values of the point B

Comment: @msqar: You probably have to scale the vector by multiplying both components with the same number, for example `let scaledVector = CGVector(dx: 2.0 * vecAB.dx, dy: 2.0 * vecAB.dy)`