# "Cannot call value of non-function type 'CGVector'" error

Tags: swift3

I am currently trying to create a Flappy Bird clone on Swift 3. I have run into an error while finishing up with my physics for my "Cow". The error I am getting is "Cannot call value of non-function type 'CGVector'"

This is for a school project. I have already tried looking at top forums on the question and adding `dx:` and `dy:` before my numbers.

This is the line of code which is getting the error:

```
Cow.physicsBody?.velocity(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))
```

This is my whole code for touchesBegan:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

Cow.physicsBody?.velocity(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))
Cow.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 60))
}
```

I expect for CGVector to work. To summarize, I am using Swift 3 and am getting this error on my physics code for a Flappy Bird clone.

Comment: May be you not creating CGVector as an object https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/1409705-scnvector3make

Comment: How would i go about doing that? Where would I put that func? I am a beginner

Comment: Not sure may be like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38030400/10634638

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody):

Unlike function `applyImpulse`

> func applyImpulse(_ impulse: CGVector)

`velocity` is a **property**

> var velocity: CGVector { get set }

You have to assign the value

```
Cow.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
```

Or shorter

```
Cow.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector.zero
```

Or shortest

```
Cow.physicsBody?.velocity = .zero
```